# Script to back up files (.batch)

Tags: loops, batch-file, backup

I'm currently using a little script that'll copy a file, rename the file and back it up in a folder for me. I've been asked if this can automatically back up every two hours. Please see my current code:

```
    @Echo Off
set "desPath="C:\User\Craig\Desktop\Back Up\"
set "extension=.mdb"
Set /P FName= File name:
set "target=%desPath%%FName%%extension%"
Echo Target = %target%
pause
copy "H:\Accounts.mdb" %target%
pause
```

This currently asks what you want it to be called then copies to my Backup folder.
I need help writing a script which asks for a name for the file then adds the date/time every two hours to the name and saves it.

02:00am: It'll save "Database020030032018.mdb"

04:00am: It'll save "Database040030032018.mdb"

06:00 so on... but automatically once the script is run. It doesnt necessarily have to be on the hour. Just two hours after its initially ran.

Thank you

Comment: Windows Scheduled Tasks?

Comment: Hello Aschipfl.
I'm on a work PC and do not have access to use this. This is why I require a script. Sorry for not clarifying.